# how to draw QString

Tags: c++, qt

How can I draw QString char by char. Here is example of what I mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.lenght(); i++){
    cout << str[i]
}
```

This is what I mean, I'm sorry for my bad explanation. I will be very grateful if anybody give me an idea how to do this.

Comment: Just add ';' after second line to compile this code.

Comment: I'm getting "The program has unexpectedly finished." erorr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the QString-Iterator:

```
QString s = "string";
for(QString::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
  qDebug() << *i;
```